# Flip the coin until a tail coming after the head

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let Z be the number of the first toss in which we see a tail
coming after a head.

What is the Expected value of Z (Mean)?

I figured out that for the Z-1 times the is the geometric for the first head appear.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest approach is to condition on the result of the first toss.

Comment: If the first flip is heads, then the first tail that you see must be preceded by heads.  If the first flip is tails, then you must keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the desired expected value by $x$. If you get heads first, you then have to wait for tails with success probability $p=\frac12$ and thus expected time $1\div\frac12=2$. If you get tails first, you're back to where you started. Thus

$$
x=1+\frac12(2+x)
$$

Solving for $x$ yields $x=4$.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am still confusing about the equation. what is the 1 means?

Comment: @Jason: No matter what the result is, it took you 1 toss to get it.